# Send pdf from Java Server to Android Device

Tags: java, android

What are the different ways to send pdf from Java Server to Android Device
and Which one the Best way

- Can We send pdf of large size(>25 MB) in JSON  to android Device
- Is there any other way to send pdf to device (i.e other then in JSON)

( Mostly Using Spring Integration)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this, one way using Jax RS,
It is not using JSON. It let the file downloaded to the device.

```
@GET
@Path("/{fileName}/excel") 
//Your Proper URL,using the fileName let you the download the specific pdf
@Produces("application/pdf")
public Response getFileInPDFFormat(@PathParam("fileName") String fileName) 
{
    String filePath="";// Your File Path

    //Put some validations here such as invalid file name or missing file name
    if(fileName == null || fileName.isEmpty())
    {
        ResponseBuilder response = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        return response.build();
    }

    File file = new File(filePath);

    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename='"+fileName+"'");


    return response.build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To send (initiate download from server side to Android) its need to have Android application installed with Google Cloud Messages [GCM](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html) and push notification message from server side to Android = start download from some link and next your Android application will start download (pdf can be accessible from web service with/without security -like JaxRS, Apache www root dir without security or some ftp too)